# Sending signal/text from Linux Machine to Labview in Window

Tags: linux, windows, labview, serial-communication

Currently I'm developing a data acquisition program for my experiment in C++ from a Linux based machine (Ubuntu), I also have many VIs in Labview who is programmed in Windows to control the instruments of the experiment (motors, Signal Generator..). The purpose is to have a 2-way communication between 2 pc, the Linux will ask which VIs to be executed, and when it's finished, send back a signal to Linux machine. 
My questions are:

1. **Can I send a signal or a command to Labview in Windows from Linux (Terminal, and it can be implemented into my C code) and vice versa? How?**
2. **TCP Labview could be a solution? Or should I try to set the inter-PC "talking" through serial communication (which is easy to setup physically)?**

Answer (score 1):

The best (also the easiest) way is to implement TCP-based client-server communication (TCP will ensure data is lossless. When using other mechanisms like UDP or serial you should always make sure your commands are received correctly).

At LabVIEW site, you will have TCP listener (server) which will listen to commands from the Linux machine at your specified port.

Upon command reception, LabVIEW code can do the work and reply by the same TCP connection.

This is very good article about your question: https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-9131

Answer (score -1):

Their are several choices for communicating between C++ and LabVIEW. (As well as Linux / Windows).

If you are willing to run LabVIEW on your linux machine you can make use of several of the LabVIEW communication architectures.  Here is NI's white paper.
http://www.ni.com/white-paper/12079/en/
Provides choices such as Shared Variable, Network Streams, Web Services, TCP/IP.

You can also take your LabVIEW code and compile it to a DLL and call it from C++ to make use of some of the above features.  If not you are likely going to have to go to the TCP/IP route or web service.

I would recommend using TCP/IP, its pretty simple to implement on both sides.
If you are more familiar with serial protocols you can also use them to communicate.